# batch file command to log the files deleted and then delete

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I was running batch file script to delete the files in particular folder.the problem is how can i log the files deleted and the date time it is getting deleted in a log file with log file nameappended with date.

```
set folder="C:\test"
cd /d %folder%
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b') do (rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @echo off
setlocal

set "YMD=" 
 FOR /F "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3" %%A IN ('WMIC Path Win32_LocalTime Get Year^,Month^,Day /Format:table') DO (

    if not defined Y set "YMD=%%B%%A%%C"

 )


 set folder="C:\test"


break>%YMD%.log
for /F "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b %folder%') do (

    echo "%%~fi" deleted at %YMD% >>%YMD%.log 
    rmdir "%%i" /s/q || del "%%i" /s/q

)
```

?

Comment: thanx for your asnswer. it is working but it  generated log file with out any name.and also it generated the log file in the same path where the fiels are goiong to be deleted

Comment: @subash  - Log file has a name - `20140820.log` , but you are right -it will be deleted...Now it's fixed - no `CD` in the given directory.